# Can't start Confluent 2.0 (apache-kafka) Schema-Registry in DC/OS

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere, marathon, dcos

DC/OS doesn't run Schema-registry and Rest-Proxy components of [confluent 2.0](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/platform.html). I've launched Confluent 2 that contains the `apache-kafka` package in DC/OS 1.7 via Marathon, see also the [Marathon app spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e7NseupQ7F6RhrGjw5pTPx87hDc0ZX1FYtUPAsgiA7M/edit?usp=sharing). As I understand, Marathon runs `kafka-scheduler.jar` from `kafka-scheduler.zip` (cf. the Marathon app spec) via a script. I didn't find any option that can specify which component to run or alternatively the source of `kafka-scheduler.jar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial implementation of Confluent Support in DC/OS included only the Kafka Broker level.   The Confluent and Mesos teams are collaborating on a more integrated offering that will include all the Confluent Platform components ... stay tuned !

Answer (score 0):

As of DC/OS 1.8/1.9 you should find all components of Confluent Platform 3.2.x which includes schema registry.